# Rails: Forms: how to make form submit and send text with one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Currently, users are using a **pull down menu** to select a post rating:

```
<%= f.select :Rating, options_for_select(["Awesome", "Good", "Meh"]) %>
```

The problem, however, is that users, intuitively might hit the submit button without actually opening the pull down and change the default "Awesome" rating.

So I am wondering if there is a way to handle this better. Perhaps by having three buttons, Awesome, Good, and Meh, that when clicked, **simultaneously send the text and submit the form.**

Do you know if rails forms can do this? If not, or if you have an alternate suggestion on how to handle this, could you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure Rails solution, you can use `button_to` to create three different forms -- one for each option.

You can also just add a bit of javascript to submit the form for the button onclick event.